# How to clone a Quote (CPQ) changing the Record type

Tags: custom-button, cpq, clone

I would like to change de record type when cloning the Quote, but it doesn't. 
What am I doing wrong?

My code:

From "Quote Custom Button or Link"

**Detail Page Button**

**Behavior**
Display in existing window without sidebar or header

**URL**

```
/{!SBQQ__Quote__c.Id}/e?clone=1&RecordTypeId=0121x000000VFmXAAW&retURL={!SBQQ__Quote__c.Id}
```

where the new Record Type Name is 'Read Edit' (RecordTypeId = 0121x000000VFmXAAW)

Answer (score 0):

The URl you are using needs little modification. Change

```
/{!SBQQ__Quote__c.Id}/e?clone=1&RecordTypeId=0121x000000VFmXAAW&retURL={!SBQQ__Quote__c.Id}
```

to

```
/{!SBQQ__Quote__c.Id}/e?clone=1&RecordType=0121x000000VFmXAAW&retURL={!SBQQ__Quote__c.Id}
```

The change here is:- You are using **RecordTypeId** whereas it should be just **RecordType**.